# проблема с подсвечиванием активного текста над блоком

Tags: javascript

Есть слайд , так же есть скрипт данного слайда , проблема в том , что не могу решить проблему с подсвечиванием активного текста над блоком , ( слайд над слайдом 3 заголовка , нужно сделать так что бы при определенном изображение над слайдом загорался нужный текст), пытался сделать аналогично dott, но не чего не вышло , необходима помощь, Спасибо!

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);
showText(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    showText(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    showText(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("success__myslides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("success__dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    }

    function showText(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("success__myslides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("success__text");
        if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";  
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: вам нужно заменить название класса в переменной dots с `success__dot` на `success__text`

Comment: Да, все заработало , но перестало работать подсвечивание активной dot

Comment: Что то наковырял активная дота отображается активный текст также отображается, но как сделать что бы было синхронно?